# not defined error in python while using class

Tags: python, function, class, self

I'm a beginner and i have been trying to get employee leave management data from user input of 'n' employees using class function.

Here are my codes to get n inputs from user for employee leave management

```
class Employee:
    n=int(raw_input("Pls enter the number of employees:"))

def __init__(self, name, idno, leavetaken, leavereqd, reason):

    self.name=name
    self.idno=idno
    self.leavetaken=leavetaken
    self.leavereqd=leavereqd
    self.reason=reason

    def Employee(self):
        print("name:", self.name,", idno:", self.idno, ", leavetaken:", self.leavetaken,", leavereqd:", self.leavereqd,", reason:", self.reason)

print "Employee.name:", Employee.name             
print "Employee.idno:", Employee.idno
print "Employee.leavetaken:", Employee.leavetaken
print "Employee.leavereqd:", Employee.leavereqd
print "Employee.reason:", Employee.reason
```

Comment: remove double underscores from __name__ and etc
You didnt get an error on `__name__` just because it's built-in function which return class name in your case

Comment: Your class does not have attribute `__idno__` (nor `idno`, for the matter). It has attribute `Idno`. Same with the other four attributes. As a side note, you attempt to print the name and other attributes of the function `Employee`, and it does not have any of them aside from `__name__`, but it is not the name you think it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying to do something like this?

```
class Employee:
    def __init__(self, name, idno, leavetaken, leavereqd, reason):
        self.name = name
        self.idno = idno
        self.leavetaken = leavetaken
        self.leavereqd = leavereqd
        self.reason = reason

    def __str__(self):
        return "Name: {}\nID No:{}\nLeave Taken: {}\nLeave Requested: {}\nLeave Reason: {}\n".format(self.name, self.idno, self.leavetaken, self.leavereqd, self.reason)

n = int(raw_input("Please enter the number of employees: "))
employees = []

# capture employee leave requests from input
for i in range(n):
    print("\n({} of {})".format(i + 1, n))
    employee = Employee(
        raw_input("Employee name: ") or "employee".format(i + 1),
        raw_input("Employee ID no: ") or str(i + 1),
        int(raw_input("Employee leave taken: ") or "0"),
        int(raw_input("Employee leave requested: ") or "0"),
        raw_input("Employee leave reason: ") or "No reason"
    )
    employees.append(employee)
print("\n")

# print captured leave requests
print("Employee leave requests:")
for employee in employees:
    print(employee)
```

Comment: That's the codes i was looking for. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Hpw to write the above codes into a csv file?? sorry. Im a beginner

Comment: There are a lot of references out there for beginners http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/systems-programming/using-the-csv-module-in-python/ Try to write the code first & post another question if you stuck again

Answer (score 0):

You are defining "Employee" twice; once as a class and then as a function. When you're trying to access the `__name__` attribute of "Employee" you accessing the function's attribute rather than the class's one (that's why the `__name__` succeeded while `__idno__` fails).

Comment: I have made changes to my code above. Still im getting the error    
Pls enter the number of employees:1
Employee.name:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python27/emplclass.py", line 15, in <module>
    print "Employee.name:", Employee.name
AttributeError: class Employee has no attribute 'name'

Comment: I see your edit. First, your __init__ function should be under the class (one indent in). Second, You are trying to access those attributes (`name`, `idno` etc.) as if they were "static" attributes. If you want to access those, first instantiate a new instance of Employee : `emp1 = Employe("John", 1, 0, 0, "reason")` and then access it's attributes `emp1.name` or your function `emp1.Employee()`.

Comment: I want to get those john 1,0,0,reason as general ones like name, id, reason etc as the no of employees and these info are user inputs so i cant define them before

Comment: Ok, so that number of employes input should be outside the class definition (also as best practice). Right above where you defined a new employee, get the input and then iterate as many times as input using `for i in range(n)` and then just like you've inputted the number of employees just input all the other stuff.

Comment: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_classes_objects.htm       im trying to make changes to the accessing attributes program by getting user inputs and by adding few more values

Comment: I'm truly sorry, I don't quite understand what you mean.

Comment: Thanks for ur help :)